# Prove that the extended real line is a smoth manifold

Tags: smooth-manifolds

I'm starting to learning the subject and I would appreciate some feedback to see if my understanding is correct. So I want to prove that the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}=\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ is a smooth manifold. That $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a topological manifold and that it is Hausdorff I think it's easy to prove. If I understand the concepts correctly, for each point $x\in\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ I need to find a neighborhood $U_x$ of $x$ and a homeomorphism $\phi_x:U_x\rightarrow\phi(U_x)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, and then I need that the transition maps $\phi_x\cdot\phi_y^{-1}:\phi_y(U_x\cap U_y)\rightarrow\phi_x(U_x\cap U_y) $ between this homeomorphisms to be $C^\infty$.

So I did the following:

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ I can take $U=\mathbb{R}$ as the open set and

\begin{align}
\phi_x=id: & \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
& x\mapsto id(x)=x
\end{align}

as the homeomorphism between them. If $x=\infty$ (conversely for $-\infty$) then I can take $U_\infty=(1,\infty]$ as the open set and map it to $[0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ using the bijection $\phi_\infty(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Now $\phi_\infty$ is continuous because any open set in $[0,1)$ can be written as the union of open intervals, furthermore the preimage of an union is the union of the preimages, and finally $\phi_\infty^{-1}((a,b))=(1/b,1/a)$ which is an open set in $\overline{R}$. Also, $\phi_\infty^{-1}=id$ which is also continuous, therefore $\phi_\infty$ is an homeomorphism between $(1,\infty]$ and $\phi((1,\infty])=[0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.

To conclude, the transition maps between points in $\mathbb{R}$ are again the identity, which is $C^\infty$. Furthermore for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we have $\phi_x\cdot\phi_\infty^{-1}:\phi_\infty(U_x\cap U_\infty)\rightarrow\phi_x(U_\infty\cap U_x)=id$, therefore $\phi_x\cdot\phi_\infty^{-1}\in C^\infty$.

I appreciate any feedback! Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the definition of manifold you have? A topological manifold? State it anyway for context's sake. Then we can verify your proof.

Comment: Sorry, hope it's clearer now!

Comment: Much better, +1.

Comment: I didn't read your stuff. But shouldn't it be obvious that ${\mathbb R}\cup\{-\infty,\infty\}$ looks like $[-1,1]$, hence is not a manifold? Have you seen an element of this space which is $>\infty$?

Comment: Is $\tan^{-1}$ with $\tan^{-1}(\pm\infty)\equiv\pm1$ an homeomorphism between the two?